# Robots.txt allow assetlinks.json

Tags: android, deep-linking, user-agent, robots.txt, android-deep-link

I want to allow robots.txt for https://myhostname/.well-known/assetlinks.json but disallow everything else.

I'm using this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Disallow: /
```

or this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /.well-known/assetlinks.json
Disallow: /
```

Which one of them is the correct one?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you think the first one is doing? It's certainly not finding `assetlinks.json` for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SilvioMayolo But I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking :D What's the correct way to allow only /.well-know..... and disallow everything else? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is enough:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /.well-known/
```

You don´t need to use "Disallow" if you don't want to prevent that the engine crawlers access on your site.